# MySQL Query Glitch

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, mysql

I have this MySQL Query glitch in my VB.NET program. 
Here is the query in VB.NET:

```
"SELECT Points FROM user WHERE Username = '" & UsernameText.Text & "';"
```

It will select the points column from the user table from the Username they entered. When I deploy this it will set the value for points to 0 on their account. What's going wrong? I'm not even inserting anything in.

Comment: What if someone enters this in your textbox: `' OR 1=1;--` ?

Comment: or: `';UPDATE user SET points=0 WHERE Username='yourname';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly why your table is updated by a select query.  But I do know you're going about building your query string all wrong.  You should do it like this instead:

```
Using cn As New MySqlConnection("your connection string here"), _
      cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT points FROM user WHERE username= @UserName")

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", UsernameText.Text)
    cn.Open()

    ''# ExecuteReader or Fill command go here, connection will be automatically closed
    ''# when control falls out of the using block, even if an exception is thrown

End Using
```

Comment: +1 I'm not sure SQL Injection is at work here, but it's worthwhile to show the OP how to use query parameters!

Answer (score 2):

2 possibilities that I can see:

1. Some other code is updating the points value
2. SQL Injection:

If the value in UsernameText.Text is

```
blah'; update user set points = 0;--
```

Then the resultant SQL will be:

```
SELECT Points FROM user where Username = 'blah'; update user set points = 0;--';
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no way a `SELECT` query can change values stored in the database.  It's a read-only command.  Either the values were already zero, or else the query is only returning zeroes (in spite of what's stored in the database), or else it's returning no rows at all.

I'd guess that your query isn't formed properly, and it's returning no rows.

You probably have a variable in your VB.NET code and its initial value is zero, to be overridden as it reads the result of the SQL query.  When the SQL query returns no rows, this variable retains its initial zero value.

So try an experiment: initialize your points variable to -99 or something and try it again.  I bet your app will display -99.

Furthermore, I'd assume the data actually in the database has not changed to zero.  Only what you display defaults to zero because your SQL query isn't functioning.

When you're debugging dynamic SQL, you need to look at the complete SQL query -- *after* you interpolate any dynamic variables into it.  It's hard to debug when you're staring at a VB.NET string expression that builds an SQL query.  It's like troubleshooting your car problems by visiting an automobile factory.

Comment: well have a something like mydata.hasrows = 0 when they login. Do you think that may be affecting the score?

Comment: If the result has no rows, that seems to support the assumption that the query isn't returning anything.  Either there's an error with the query, or else it's simply not matching anything in the database.

Comment: No its not that, its that the hasrows function comes in during login. When login is successful it will retrieve the points on your account.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQl, the fields and tables are denoted by a apostrophe/backtick in this case...

```
"SELECT `Points` FROM `user` WHERE `Username`= '" & UsernameText.Text & "';"
```

Check if that works. Hope it helps.

Comment: sigh...it seems this site has escaped 'em backticks and apostrophes.... Points, user and Username are enclosed in apostrophes or backticks...

Comment: I edited the post to format code so we can see the backticks.

Comment: Nope it doesn't work. Even if I put it in my MYSQL Query Browser it will set the value of point to 0.